# Confused about performance implications of Sync

Tags: performance, rust, synchronization

I have a question about the marker trait `Sync` after reading [Extensible Concurrency with the Sync and Send Traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch16-04-extensible-concurrency-sync-and-send.html).

Java's "synchronize" means **blocking**, so I was very confused about how a Rust struct with `Sync` implemented whose method is executed on multiple threads would be effective.

I searched but found no meaningful answer. I'm thinking about it this way: every thread will get the struct's reference synchronously (blocking), but call the method in parallel, is that true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java: Accesses to this object from multiple threads become a *synchronized* sequence of actions when going through this codepath.
Rust: It is safe to access this type *synchronously* through a reference from multiple threads.

(The two points above are not canonical definitions, they are just demonstrations how similar words can be used in sentences to obtain different meanings)

`synchronized` is implemented as a mutual exclusion lock at runtime. `Sync` is a compile time promise about runtime properties of a specific type that allows other types depend on those properties through trait bounds. A `Mutex` just happens to be one way one can provide `Sync` behavior. Immutable types usually provide this behavior too without any runtime cost.

Generally you shouldn't rely on words having exactly the same meaning in different contexts. Java IO stream != java collection stream != RxJava reactive stream ~= tokio Stream. C volatile != java volatile. etc. etc.
Ultimately the prose matters a lot more than the keyword which are just shorthands.

Comment: Thanks. I'm learning rust, so know it little.  From your answer I can't  make it clearly. On an mutable struct reference Rust will apply `Mutex` so it blocking struct method call, is it exactly what you mean? But on immutable struct method call I can't grab the soul from you sentences. Please elaborate it , thanks

Comment: Accessing immutable data is usually safe and incurs no runtime cost, unlike a mutex, what more do you need to know?